# How to achieve memoir chapter style in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I quite like the chapter style on Page 28 of http://tug.ctan.org/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf. How can I achieve such a style in ConTeXt? Also, how can I instruct ConTeXt to use a particular font for chapter/section/subsections in a particular color?

Comment: I think you have a greater chance to get help if you include the example here, and perhaps also show some effort. As it is not, we need to go into that pdf file, find the right page, and start from scratch. (I did not down vote.)

Comment: @mickep I will edit the question and update with my effort.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes, which shows a variety of chapter styles independent of the source document format. In particular, take a look at [Tarmes](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/tree/main/tarmes), [Handrit](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/tree/main/handrit), and [Boschet](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/tree/main/boschet).